# Is there a technical term for the situation where a possessive noun compounded with another noun form the name of a very specific object?

Tags: nouns, possessives, apostrophe

I'm not a linguist so please excuse this clumsily worded question: Is there a technical term for the situation where a possessive noun compounded with another noun form the name of a very specific object, such as "housemaid's knee", or "bosun's chair"? How about where a proper noun and another noun are combined, as in "Adam's apple", or Hammurabi's code"? Does the same linguistic term apply?

Comment: They would be called noun compounds, or compound nouns. There is a large literature on them, but most of [the technical terms for types of compounds are Sanskrit words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit_grammar#Compounds). I think this would probably be a _bahuvrihi_ compound, but I'm no expert. It might also be _tatpurusha_, since genitive is a case relation.

Comment: Though they have distinct idiomatic meanings, I can't see any reason to call them compounds. Since they are written as separate words, they are best seen as syntactic constructions. "Housemaid's knee", for example is a noun phrase consisting of the genitive noun "housemaids' as determiner and "knee" as head.